# How to pass params with body in flutter http put method

Tags: http, flutter

Hi i am trying to pass the query prams to http put method.

Here i am trying in this way

```
     var queryParameters = {
    'id': '285',

  };

      return http.put(
          'http://domainname${queryParameters}', body: json.encode(formData)
          ,
          headers: {
            'Authorization': receivedToken,
            'X-Oc-Store-Id': receivedstoreid,

          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
 var body = jsonEncode({
  "email": "${emailController.text}",
  "password": "${passwordController.text}"
});
```

.

```
var response = await http.put("http://domainname + /${id}", body: body, headers: {
     'Authorization': receivedToken,
     'X-Oc-Store-Id': receivedstoreid,
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
```

Comment: I have to pass both body and params